# Facebook loggin button on android

Tags: android, facebook, button

I try to add a facebook loggin button on my project, but when I test the error log show me this: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Log in attempt failed: FacebookActivity could not be started. Please make sure you added FacebookActivity to the AndroidManifest.
But I have put the FacebookActivity on the Manifest like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gdp.eparking" >


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityNuevoUsuario"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<activity android:name=".ActivityLogueo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".ActivityPrincipal"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

I need others permission?

Comment: Have you added your app id in your strings.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting your activities outside the application tag, your corrected manifest should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.gdp.eparking" >


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityNuevoUsuario"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActivityLogueo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActivityPrincipal"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
         android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
         android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```